# How could I build a single .rlib with all dependencies included?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I build my rlib with `cargo build —-lib`. However when I use it with `rustc main.rc —-extern mylib=mylib.rlib`, I got an compile error `can’t find crate for xxx which mylib depends on`.

How could I get a rlib with all dependencies included?

Comment: You're mixing cargo usage with invoking rustc directly?  That may be a different question than doing it all via cargo.

Comment: Maybe this is the real problem. What is the correct way to sharing compiled library across projects then?

Comment: My first intention was static library. However according to [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html) `rlib` is the better option.

Answer (score 1):

> How could I get a rlib with all dependencies included?

You can't. An `.rlib` file is the result of compiling *one* crate.

> What is the correct way to sharing compiled library across projects then?

The Rust toolchain is not designed to support this in general.

One of the main reasons for this is that libraries have *Cargo features*  which define whether certain conditionally-compiled code should be enabled or not, and libraries of the same major version are expected to not be duplicated. Putting these properties together means that you can't expect that compiling a library and its dependencies separately will produce a correct result (because some of the included dependencies might be missing features required by the separately compiled dependent, but must not be duplicated) — compilation needs to look at the *entire graph* of library crate dependencies.

You can share the cost of compiling one library to be used by another set of packages by putting all those packages in one [*workspace*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html), but workspaces are designed for compiling a set of closely related packages and are not necessarily suitable for combining arbitrary ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’m new to rust and going to learn about workspace